# git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git, github, git-push

I created a new remote repository and tried to use `git push -u origin master` command to push my local files into the new repository the first time after I `add` it and `commit` it. However, it pops up this `git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`. How can I fix this fatal error?

I've tried this
[How to solve Permission denied (publickey) error when using Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643502/how-to-solve-permission-denied-publickey-error-when-using-git/42641637#42641637)
It seems that the question in this link happens in the first time using git. I've used my git for a while, do I still need to follow this solution? Can anyone gives me a more specific solution?

This the fatal error that I got

```
C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\React-Practice App\my-app>git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean

C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\React-Practice App\my-app>git push -u origin master
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GitHub Error Message - Permission denied (publickey)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940626/github-error-message-permission-denied-publickey)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Permission+denied+publickey

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You’re accessing GitHub through SSH. First generate an SSH key pair; then add the public key to GitHub.

Generate key pair, github prefers the "Ed25519 algorithm"

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "your_email@example.com"
```

It still allows using rsa for systems that don't support Ed25519

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C “youremail@example.com”
```

See more at https://help.github.com/en/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent and https://help.github.com/en/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account

Comment: I've use this command ```ls -al ~/.ssh``` to check out whether I have a existing ssh key. The result is I already have one. Therefore, why do I need to generate a new one, if I already have one?

Comment: Navigate to github profile > Settings > SSH and GPG keys > New SSH key. In the text-field paste the content of `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` file. See more at the second link in answer.

Comment: I already had a ssh key, and it is encrypted. So I needed to unlock it first by adding it (on a mac) like this: `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`, where `id_rsa` is the secret key of your ssh. Then type in my encryption password for it.

Comment: On **Ubuntu** after running `ssh-add id_rsa`  I received the error _could not open a connection to your authentication agent_  If you ever run into this . Run  1)  `exec ssh-agent bash`  2) `ssh-add <your_key>`   .)  [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_px5jRgxF3Q)

Comment: For some weird reason, suddenly I can't reach gh with ssh any more, following the step @Knogobert suggested helps me. So weird. Because I remember I did it already, for sure.

Answer (score 52):

I had this problem because I used a non-standard location for my key like @Mon did. In my case, I did not use the default file name because I have more than one key on my system. So it's not possible to resolve it simply by moving or renaming.

The solution is to edit or create `~/.ssh/config` (OpenSSH docs for [`config`](https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/config) and [Configuring the Location of Identity Keys](https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/identity-key#configuring-the-location-of-identity-keys)) to contain the following:

```
Host github.com
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github-key
```

- Do *not* edit line 3 to reflect your own username. The username should be `git` (see [github docs](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/error-permission-denied-publickey#always-use-the-git-user)).
- Edit line 4 to reflect the location of your key.

If you already have a `config` file, it would be worthwhile having a look at what's there before futzing around. It never hurts to make a copy before editing.

The above assumes that you have created the key, put it on github, that you actually *do* have permissions, and everything else is as it should be, but still encountering error.

Comment: after failing to push i tried many solutions but this worked for me also after transforming my key to new open ssh format with putty gen

Comment: This. And for a new key make sure to add it on the server: `$ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"` and `$ ssh-add path/to/your/key`.

Comment: This was all I needed to do, as I had a non-standard name

Comment: After banging my head against all the github help pages and error pages, this is always the (last) solution.

Comment: Generated new key for bitbucket. Loaded it in Pageant, saved as openssh format, updated config with bitbucket.org. 
It worked like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 24):

Had the same issue even after adding ssh keys on github.

Fixed it by running this command

`ssh -vT git@github.com`

Comment: Thank you very much! It showed the error logs and found out that git uses specific path (~/.ssh) and filename (id_<type>) when trying to authenticate. I shouldn't have renamed that.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem with the Github today.

Comment: Great stuff! Thanks. I worked down through all of the above and finally this got me going...

Answer (score 2):

I was having the worst time getting this setup and had the same error pop up.

How I fixed my issue was not having the `.git` folder as root and using another user to access it by using `sudo`. I changed the folder permission to the user:

```
chown -R user:user .git/
```

Answer (score 1):

When I had this problem, I ended up having a typo in my git remote origin url. Maybe you can double check that everything is spelled correctly without any additional unintended keystrokes?

Answer (score 1):

On Windows there are sometimes multiple version of SSH installed.
It results in conflict when using git:
**git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey)**.
To resolve it, just point the correct version in environment variable:

setx /m GIT_SSH C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best method copying the public key content from `~./ssh` folder is `clip` command. Since selecting manually and then copying may introduce additional spaces etc.

Here are the steps I would follow.

###### 1- Check to see if you already have a key pair

`ls -lah ~/.ssh`

in CMD: `dir/W %USERPROFILE%\.ssh`

###### 2- If you have key pairs, copy the content of the public key to memory

`cat ~/.ssh/id_xxxxx.pub | clip`

xxxxx could be `ed25519` or `rsa`

in CMD: `type %USERPROFILE%\.ssh\id_rsa.pub | clip`

###### 3- If you don't have the key pairs, just generate with either one of the following commands:

(first one is preferred).

`ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "your_email@example.com`

or

`ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com`

and then do the step 2.

###### 4- Navigate to [github](https://github.com/settings/ssh/new) and then paste the memory content that you copied with `clip`

NOTE: Same steps will work with BitBucket, GitLab and Azure repos.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem because i have a ssh key to bitbucket.org and i am trying to add a new one for github.com.

So the solution was:

- Configure a new ssh-key
- To delegate which key you must use to conect with github.com, update or create your SSH configuration file `(~/.ssh/config)` with the following setting:

```
## My current config
 Host bitbucket.org
 AddKeysToAgent yes
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/keyOfBitbucket
## End

 Host github.com
 AddKeysToAgent yes   
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/keyOfGithub
```

Answer (score 1):

I was using `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:g33kfleek/"your repository"` to set my repository origin then I fixed it by using:

```
'git remote set-url origin https://github.com/"username"/"your repo"'
```

then you run :

```
git push -u origin main
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 1):

The "Permission denied (publickey)" error indicates an issue with the SSH key authentication when trying to push to your GitHub repository. Here's a step-by-step guide to resolving this issue:

#### 1. **Check SSH Key:**

1. **Check Existing SSH Keys:**
   Ensure that you have an existing SSH key. Run the following command to list your existing keys:

   ```bash
   ls -al ~/.ssh
   ```

   Look for files named `id_rsa` or `id_rsa.pub`.
2. **Generate a New SSH Key (If Needed):**
   If you don't have an SSH key or want to generate a new one, you can use the following command:

   ```bash
   ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"
   ```

   Follow the prompts to generate a new key. Make sure to replace "your_email@example.com" with your actual email address.
3. **Add SSH Key to SSH Agent:**
   Start the SSH agent and add your private key:

   ```bash
   eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
   ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
   ```

#### 2. **Add SSH Key to GitHub:**

1. **Copy the SSH Key to Clipboard:**
   Use the following command to copy your SSH key to the clipboard:

   ```bash
   clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
   ```

   If the `clip` command is not available, you can open the `id_rsa.pub` file with a text editor and manually copy its contents.
2. **Add SSH Key to GitHub:**

   - Go to your GitHub account settings.
   - Navigate to "SSH and GPG keys" or "SSH keys."
   - Click on "New SSH key" or "Add SSH key."
   - Paste your key into the provided field and give it a title.

#### 3. **Update Remote URL:**

1. **Check Current Remote URL:**
   Verify the current remote URL for your repository:

   ```bash
   git remote -v
   ```
2. **Update Remote URL (if needed):**
   If the URL is using HTTPS, you may want to update it to use SSH:

   ```bash
   git remote set-url origin git@github.com:yourusername/yourreponame.git
   ```

   Replace `yourusername` and `yourreponame` with your GitHub username and repository name.

#### 4. **Retry Git Push:**

Try pushing your code again:

```bash
git push -u origin master
```

This should prompt you for your SSH passphrase, and after entering it, the push should proceed without the "Permission denied (publickey)" error.

Comment: yes, if clip dcommand does not exist on your stystem, try cat

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me was that I was on a new PC, trying to access the same account as my other computer. It's not enough to create a new SSH, you also need to register it in your GitHub profile. Once I did, problem solved itself.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem while trying to push my files in Github from remote repository. This following steps helped to solve the problem:

1. `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"`
   Use this command in Git bash to create a new ssh key. Enter your email which you have used in your Github account.
2. A new ssh key will be created with file names `id_rsa`. Press enter
3. Again it will ask you to create a passphrase, just press enter twice
4. `clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`
   enter this command to copy the ssh key
5. Now goto `github -> settings -> SSH and GPG keys -> new ssh`
   give a title and paste the copied key