# git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey) on Windows

Tags: git, public-key

I am facing a problem with git, no matter which command i execute i get the following error:

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

By trying `ssh -vT git@github.com`:
`Hi emaborsa! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0`

I am working on windows 10, in the WSL the same settings work.

I already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57734669/gitgithub-com-permission-denied-publickey). I already created a new ssh-key, added it to my ssh keys on github, did not help.

I cannot checkout any github repo using ssh, always the same error.

I updated git to the last version.

Until yesterday it worked fine. The same for my collegues.

Comment: The issue might be that you don't have permission with the repo you're accessing, not with git?

Comment: I created the repo, i am committing on it since months. However, I cannot checkout any other repo using ssh.

Comment: The more probable cause is that git doesn't use your identity (public key) as ssh used when invoked directly. Could you `git clone --verbose`?

Comment: I generally work with `ssh-agent` so git and ssh can equally find my identities. Do you?

Comment: `git clone --verbose` leads to the same error. We've newer worked with `ssh-agent`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days we found the problem. It was neither a git problem nor the firewall. The Admins activated the Custom `Home Folder` in the `Active Directory`, that leaded that git could not fine the ssh key and so was not able to access the private repositories.