# Github permission denied: ssh add agent has no identities

Tags: bash, github, ssh, permission-denied, public-key

This is my first time accessing GitHub and I'm not experienced using a console. I am on a MacBook using Bash. When I try to access GitHub, I get this:

```
git clone git@github.com:dhulihan/league-of-legends-data-scraper.git
Cloning into 'league-of-legends-data-scraper'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I've tried following the instructions on Github page about permission being denied.

When I use `ssh -vT git@github.com`, I get the following:

```
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.252.129] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/XXXX/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/XXXX/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/XXXX/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/XXXX/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version libssh-0.6.0
debug1: no match: libssh-0.6.0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/XXXX/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/XXXX/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/XXXX/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Next, `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"` returns "Agent pid 2314",
however `ssh-add -l` returns "The agent has no identities."

And that is where I am stuck.

Comment: Do you *have* an SSH key created? Do you have it listed with your github account? Do you have the key on your mac?

Comment: I was looking for the answer to that question (not being familiar with this whole system), and found this: https://mac.github.com/ It solved all my problems. I highly recommend it. Thanks for the push in the right direction, Etan!

Comment: You might want to add that an an answer to this question (with further details about how it solved your problem) and accept your answer.

Comment: Okay, I've submitted the answer. SO is telling me I can only accept it in 2 hours.

Answer (score 335):

Full details in this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363404/ssh-add-command-does-not-add-my-identity-to-ssh-agent).

In summary, when `ssh-add -l` returns “The agent has no identities”, it means that keys used by `ssh` (stored in files such as `~/.ssh/id_rsa`, `~/.ssh/id_dsa`, etc.) are either missing, they are not known to `ssh-agent`, which is the authentication agent, or that their permissions are set incorrectly (for example, world writable).

If your keys are missing or if you have not generated any, use `ssh-keygen -t rsa`, then `ssh-add` to add them.

If keys exist but are not known to `ssh-agent` (like if they are in a non-standard folder), use `ssh-add /path/to/my-non-standard-ssh-folder/id_rsa` to add them.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17846529/could-not-open-a-connection-to-your-authentication-agent) if you are having trouble with `ssh-add` or `ssh-agent`.

Comment: Thank you @Doedoe for a link to a nice and short answer.
And for those who have keyS (ie multiple Git accounts), you might have to use `ssh-add /path/to/keyX` for each, especialy if they have non-standard names. Details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225862/multiple-github-accounts-ssh-config/17158985#17158985 (a nice answer)

Comment: Thanks for this.  I got stuck here.. but I realized that I need to run `ssh-add` *again* after resolving the permissions part of the issue.  After this, `ssh -vT git@github.com` did not work.  I did need to add the *absolute* path like the commenter above mentioned.  Then, it was all gravy.

Comment: In second case I forgot my passphrase and I've recovered it using https://help.github.com/articles/how-do-i-recover-my-ssh-key-passphrase/

Comment: I am facing the same problem where the keys exist but I need to re-add them frequently while signing commits. Is there a way to add them permanently?

Comment: this is the best explanation, I read so far.

Answer (score 189):

try this:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

worked for me

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please explain your code, so your fellow users can understand what's going on. Cheers.

Comment: When you reboot your keys are gone and you have to 'ssh-add' them again.

Comment: @Louwki Yeah... that's super annoying. Do you know a way around that?

Comment: @ChrisCirefice just do the ssh-add with a parameter to add them to your keychain permanently. ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/[your-private-key]

Comment: In my case, file permissions was wrong for private key. Fixed by `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa`, then `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

Comment: gotta know the paraphrase or else you'll be creating another private key

Comment: `ssh-add -l` doesn't work, but `ssh-add` works. Why?

Comment: I also had to run `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa` after

Answer (score 57):

**THE 2019 ANSWER for macOS Sierra & High Sierra & Catalina:**

*PS: most of the other answers will have you to create a new ssh key ... but you don't need to do that :)*

*As described in detail on https://openradar.appspot.com/27348363, macOS/OS X till Yosemite used to remember SSH keys added by command `ssh-add -K <key>`*

**So here are the 4 steps i had to take in order for it to work:**

**1:** `ssh-add ~/.ssh/PATH_TO_YOUR_SSH_PRIVATE_KEY (e.g. ~/.ssh/id_rsa)`

**2:** Add the following in `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host * 
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile PATH_TO_YOUR_SSH_PRIVATE_KEY (e.g. ~/.ssh/id_rsa)
```

**3:** make sure to remove any gitconfig entry that use osxkeychain helper:

```
 https://github.com/gregory/dotfiles/commit/e38000527fb1a82b577f2dcf685aeefd3b78a609#diff-6cb0f77b38346e0fed47293bdc6430c6L48
```

**4:** restart your terminal for it to take effect.

Comment: Great answer, I was going to mention this myself! Apparently, [OS X 10.12.2 and later doesn't automatically load identities into ssh-agent](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent) (which I personally think is a really stupid usability decision, but I understand the security implications). So, you need to modify the SSH configuration to load them manually. I just wish the error output would better lead to a solution, rather than an hour of searching the internet.

Comment: I tried this answer but it seems like a step where the key is added again using `ssh-add -K <key>` is needed after 2.
@ChrisCirefice 's [link](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent) seems to indicate so.

Comment: This works with Amazon Linux server as well

Comment: @magicgrez is possible to add 2 working agents  with different identities ?

Answer (score 16):

I have been stucked a while on the same problem, which I eventually resolved.

**My problem**: I could not execute any push. I could check & see my remote (using `git remote -v`), but when I executed `git push origin master`, it returned : `Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository.` and so.

**How I solved it :**

- **I generated a key** using `ssh-keygen -t rsa`. Entering a name for the key file (when asked) was useless.
- I could then **add the key (to git)**: `ssh-add /Users/federico/.ssh/id_rsa` , which successfully returned `Identity added: /Users/myname/.ssh/id_rsa (/Users/myname/.ssh/id_rsa)`
- **I added the SSH key to github** [using this help page](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/).
- Having tried all the commands in Github's 'Permission denied publickey' help page, only the `ssh-add -l` command worked / seemed useful (after having ran the previous steps), it successfully returned my key. [The last step](https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey/#verify-the-public-key-is-attached-to-your-account) shows you where to check your public key on your GitHub page. And this command will help you check all your keys : `ls -al ~/.ssh`.

Then the push command eventually worked !

I hope this will help !
Best luck to all.

Answer (score 15):

Run the following commands:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
ssh-add /Users/*yourUserNameHere*/.ssh/id_rsa** 
pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub**
```

Go to your Github account : https://github.com/settings/profile

1) Click : SSH and GPG keys

2) New SSH Key and Past it there

3) Add SSH Key

Done!

Comment: Yup - if you've gone through the other steps of creating the id_rsa.pub file, copy and paste that pbcopy line, which copies the key to your clipboard and follow @zouhair instructions - github needs to know your key.  Particularly if you're using 2FA.

Comment: I'm slightly confused because the current docs say git creates github_rsa / github_rsa.pub. I have both in my /.ssh directory and yet I can't seem to "get permission." I've created copies in the same directory using the id_rsa to no avail.

Comment: thank you! i'd been re-trying this and for whatever reason this worked for me, thanks so much. very easy to read and understand and execute.

Comment: easiest way to handle git ssh issue

Answer (score 9):

## tl;dr

```
ssh-add # no parameter
# Identity added: /home/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa (user@host)
```

## Further readings

#### two files necessary in the ssh - user - folder:

```
ls ~/.ssh
id_rsa id_rsa.pub
```

If the files are not there, enter command `ssh-keygen`

Now start the ssh-agent:

```
eval `ssh-agent -s`
```

#### Verify

```
ssh-add -l
# voila:
2048 SHA256:<key one> user@host (RSA)
```

#### Bonus

check the local `SHA256` from above with the Github `SHA256` from your user settings -> SSH Keys. If they are equal you should be able to push/pull to/from Github using your keys.

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me:
`chmod 700 .ssh 
 chmod 600 .ssh/id_rsa 
 chmod 644 .ssh/id_rsa.pub`

Then, type this:
`ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

Comment: I don't think the question is about `~/.ssh` permissions. Still, you could greatly improve your answer by adding the full command (here `chmod`) and explaining what this does and why it's needed.

Answer (score 6):

first of all you need to go in your ssh directory
for this type following command in your terminal in mac or whatever you use in window

```
cd ~/.ssh
```

now it is in the ssh
here you can find all you ssh key/files related to your all projects. now, type the following command to show you if any ssh key available

```
ls
```

this will show you all available ssh, in my case there were two
now, you will need to start an agent to add a ssh in it. For this type following command

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
```

now last but not least you will add a ssh in this agent type following command

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/your-ssh
```

replace

> replace your-ssh with your ssh file name which you got a list form second step `ls command`

Answer (score 6):

For my mac Big Sur, with gist from answers above, following steps work for me.

```
$ ssh-keygen -q -t rsa -N 'password' -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

And added ssh public key to git hub by following instruction;

https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account

If all gone well,
you should be able to get the following result;

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
Hi user_name! You've successfully authenticated,...
```

Answer (score 5):

This could cause for any new terminal, the agent id is different.
You need to add the Private key for the agent

```
$ ssh-add <path to your private key>
```

Answer (score 1):

One additional element that I realized is that typically .ssh folder is created in your root folder in Mac OS X /Users/. If you try to use ssh -vT git@github.com from another folder it will give you an error even if you had added the correct key.

You need to add the key again (ssh-add 'correct path to id_rsa') from the current folder to authenticate successfully (assuming that you have already uploaded the key to your profile in Git)

Answer (score 1):

Steps for BitBucket:

if you dont want to generate new key, **SKIP ssh-keygen**

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Copy the public key to clipboard:

```
clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Login to Bit Bucket:
Go to View Profile -> Settings -> SSH Keys (In Security tab)
Click Add Key, 
Paste the key in the box, add a descriptive title

Go back to Git Bash :

```
ssh-add -l
```

You should get :

```
2048 SHA256:5zabdekjjjaalajafjLIa3Gl/k832A /c/Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)
```

Now: `git pull` should work

Comment: `if you dont want to generate new keySKIP ssh-keygen` is misleading better: `step needed if no ssh rsa key created`. I would add the necessary `ssh-agent` command to start the agent, otherwise `ssh-add` will error with `Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.`.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue after restoring a hard drive from a backup.

**My problem:** 
I could check & see my remote (using git remote -v), but when I executed git push origin master, it returned : Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

I already had an SSH folder and SSH keys, and adding them via Terminal (`ssh-add /path/to/my-ssh-folder/id_rsa`) successfully added my identity, but I still couldn't push and still got the same error.  Generating a new key was a bad idea for me, because it was tied to other very secure permissions on AWS.

It turned out the link between the key and my Github profile had broken.

**Solution:** 
Re-adding the key to Github in Profile > Settings > SSH and GPG keys resolved the issue.

**Also:**
My account had 2-factor authentication set up. When this is the case, if Terminal requests credentials, use your username - but NOT your Github password.  For 2-factor authentication, you need to use your authentication code (for me, this was generated by Authy on my phone, and I had to copy it into Terminal for the pw).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Linux or Windows open terminal or cmd in directory you want your keys in. Create a pair of private-public key

```
 $ ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "your_email@example.com"
```

If you are using a legacy system that doesn't support the Ed25519 algorithm, use:

```
 $ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"
```

> Generating public/private ALGORITHM key pair.
> Enter a file in which to save the key (/c/Users/YOU/.ssh/id_ALGORITHM):[Press enter any name you like your private public keys file to be]

> Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): [Type a passphrase or enter for without it]

> Enter same passphrase again: [Type a passphrase or enter for without it]

Now, in Linux

```
$ sudo cp <filename without .pub ending>  ~/.ssh
```

In Windows simply copy the <filename without .pub ending> file in this `C:\Users\your_username\.ssh` directory

And then

```
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/<filename without .pub ending>
```

It may work now!

Answer (score 0):

After struggling for long I was finally able to resolve this issue on Windows, For me the User env variable GIT_SSH was set to point to

> "C:\Program Files(x86)\WinScp\PuTTY\plink.exe"

which was installed along with WinScp. I changed the pointing to use default **ssh.exe** which comes with [git-scm](https://git-scm.com/downloads) "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe"

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me also:
chmod 700 .ssh
chmod 600 .ssh/id_rsa
chmod 644 .ssh/id_rsa.pub

Then, type this: ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it could be useful to check `~/.ssh/config`

it should look like this

```
Host github.com
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

`id_rsa` can be different if you linked a different key.