# Mac ZSH shell "forgets" ssh keys

Tags: git, macos, github, ssh, zsh

I'm trying to get Git to work, which keeps insisting that I don't have the correct access right (Permission denied, publickey), which lead me to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26505980/github-permission-denied-ssh-add-agent-has-no-identities), suggesting to inspect `ssh-add`

I noticed that, indeed, `ssh-add -l` returned

> The agent has no identities.

So, I added an identity

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/ssh_key
```

Which returned exit code 0 (from `echo $?`)

Now, `ssh-add -l` shows that I have a key added. However, once I quit and re-open terminal, the key disappears. `ssh-add -l` returns "The agent has no identities." all over again.

Does anyone know how I can add the key so that it sticks?

Comment: Does `ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/ssh_key` work?

Comment: Does this answer your question - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254468/macos-sierra-doesn-t-seem-to-remember-ssh-keys-between-reboots?

Comment: Are you doing anything special to (re)start `ssh-agent` in the first place? A freshly restarted agent has no keys initially. By default, though, `ssh-agent` is started when you first log in, independently of any shell sessions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [add the ssh-add -K to your `~/.bash_profile`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/448366/7490)

But check first if your SSH connection is working with a key *not* passphrase protected:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -P "" -f ~/.ssh/test
```

(register `test.pub` to the remote server  `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` or the remote GitHub profile SSH page)

```
 ssh -i ~/.ssh/test user@remote_server
 # or, if this is github
 ssh -T -i ~/.ssh/test git@github.com
```

Comment: This worked, though by extension I added `ssh-add -K` to `~/.zshrc`