# GitHub SSH Key claiming it is not used

Tags: git, github

Why, under Settings => SSH keys, on my GitHub account does it say;

> Added on Oct 24, 2014 by GitHub for Mac — Never used

Never used? I've used it! I've got plenty of contributions showing up on my profile. From **that** machine!

I have another key that says, quite rightly;

> Last used within the last day.

...That one is from a different machine.

Comment: This is very sensitive to your working environment.  Do you have multiple keys?  Do you use some kind of ssh-agent?  Do you use some kind of ssh-agent-forwarding?  Have you tried getting SSH to be verbose when communicating with github?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your contributions may be from that machine, but you need to check how you have set up your remotes

try the following command:

```
git remote -v
```

That will list your remotes

If it is something like

> origin    https://github.com/......

You are connecting over https, and not SSH

You'll need to remove that remote -

> git remote rm origin

Then, on your github repository page, see the following:

[image]

Click the SSH link, and copy that. It should start with `git@github.com`

Then, add that as the remote-

> git remote add origin git@github.com:.... etc

Comment: After I tried those commands, I got essentially the same problem as this guy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940626/github-error-message-permission-denied-publickey. I followed the suggested guide in one of the answers (https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/) and now it all seems to be working. So thank you!

Comment: interesting on that rm vs remove command though. The git prompt suggested `add`, `rename`, `remove`, `set-head` etc. So I just had a punt on `remove`

Comment: Instead of removing remote, use `set-url` instead. https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/managing-remote-repositories#changing-a-remote-repositorys-url