# Unable to complete git submodule update

Tags: git

I create a new organization ABC in my company's github and then forked some repos from another organization to that repo.

I have a project that needs to use `xyz-project`'s repo as a submodule.
So its .gitmodule looks like:

```
[submodule "xyz-project"]
    path = xyz-project
    url = git@github.mycompany.com:ABC/xyz-project.git
```

However on doing the `git submodule update`, I run into the following error:

```
Cloning into 'xyz-project'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Clone of 'git@github.mycompany.com:ABC/xyz-project.git' into submodule path
'xyz-project' failed
```

I am the creator of ABC organization. Why don't I have access to the above repo which I have just forked into my own repo?

Comment: It's trying to update the submodule with a public key, and it's a private repo. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940626/github-error-message-permission-denied-publickey

Comment: What is the output of `ssh git@github.com`?

Comment: Following ChrisH's link, I changed the links to HTTPS style and it worked.