# Unable to push to GitHub

Tags: git, github

I am using Git GUI (or Git CMD) for Windows 10, and have previously pushed a git repository to my GitHub account. That is, I have an SSH key associated with my Git account. Today I am unable to push new changes to that same repository. I receive the error:

```
Pushing to git@github.com:[username]/[project_name].git
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: Does `ssh git@github.com` from Git Bash produce a message like "Hi <username>! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GitHub Error Message - Permission denied (publickey)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940626/github-error-message-permission-denied-publickey)

Comment: No, `ssh git@github.com` produces the message "git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey)."

Comment: Then you did not register your public key correctly.  Do that again.

Comment: You are right. Deleting my SSH key on GitHub and re-adding it did the trick.

Comment: However, it appears that I have to delete and re-add the SSH key every day. Why would that be?