# Permission denied (publickey)!

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, native-base

Im trying to install [native base with web support](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase-KitchenSink/tree/web-support)

and when i run this command

```
git clone git@github.com:GeekyAnts/NativeBase-KitchenSink.git
```

it give me this error

> git clone git@github.com:GeekyAnts/NativeBase-KitchenSink.git Cloning
>   into 'NativeBase-KitchenSink'... Permission denied (publickey). fatal:
>   Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

how can i solve it ?

Comment: didn't it asked for keys (password), while you were trying to clone

Comment: can you share complete output from your terminal

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GitHub Error Message - Permission denied (publickey)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940626/github-error-message-permission-denied-publickey)

Answer (score 0):

possible duplicate of [public key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643502/git-permission-denied-publickey/42641637#comment88600085_42641637)

I solved my problem with that link