# Permission Denied for deploying in GitHub using travis-CI

Tags: node.js, github, ssh, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I am working on a project which I want to publish in GitHub pages. To automate the deploying process I'm using [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/). For this I have created a **deploy.sh** file, which has the following code.

```
# build
npm run docs:build

# navigate into the build output directory
cd docs/.vuepress/dist

# if you are deploying to a custom domain
# echo 'www.example.com' > CNAME


git add -A
git commit -m 'deploy'

# if you are deploying to https://<USERNAME>.github.io
# git push -f git@github.com:<USERNAME>/<USERNAME>.github.io.git master

# if you are deploying to https://<USERNAME>.github.io/<REPO>
 git push -f git@github.com:<username>/<repo>.git master:gh-pages

cd -
```

I have added this in my **.travis.yml** file, which is below

```
language: nodejs
node_js:
  - "lts/*"
before_script:
   - npm install
script:
 - bash ./scripts/deploy.sh
```

Now when I push my code to the master, In travis-ci.org it shows that the build is failed, with the following outputs,

```
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.253.113' to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
The command "bash ./scripts/deploy.sh" exited with 128.
```

I have followed other SO answers of the same type of errors like this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940626/github-error-message-permission-denied-publickey/12940681#12940681) and also followed [the way](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent) to generate and adding ssh key to my GitHub account but no success. I will be grateful if you could help me out. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to push via ssh then travis needs to have access to the private part of the ssh key you generated. What you want to do is use the travis cli gem to encrypt the private key, add it to your repo and during the deploy stage decrypt it again and use it.
Here's a [step-by-step](https://github.com/dwyl/learn-travis/blob/master/encrypted-ssh-keys-deployment.md)