# How to fix github permission denied when ssh is normal

Tags: github, permissions

[Testing your SSH connection](https://help.github.com/articles/testing-your-ssh-connection/)

- Step1.1
  ssh -T git@github.com
  Hi githubname! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
- Step1.2
  ssh-add -l -E md5
  4096 MD5:6b:4f:0e:27:d8:8f:e5:89:c7:15:71:2d:60:d1:e6:ef /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)

#### clone from github

- Step2
  sudo git clone --recursive git@github.com:skilion/onedrive.git

  > Cloning into 'onedrive'...
  > Permission denied (publickey).
  > fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
  > Please make sure you have the correct access rights
  > and the repository exists.

Reference
[GitHub Error Message - Permission denied (publickey)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940626/github-error-message-permission-denied-publickey)

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be running git with sudo, and therefore using the root user's SSH credentials. Try running it without sudo, or clone from the HTTPS url, like so:

```
# SSH URL (using your credentials)
git clone --recursive git@github.com:skilion/onedrive.git

# HTTPS URL (public repo, so no creds needed)
# The 'sudo' here is likely optional, and should only be used if you really know you need it
sudo git clone --recursive https://github.com/skilion/onedrive.git
```

Hope this helps!