# git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey) ERROR

Tags: reactjs, git, github, iterm2, iterm

I've have been trying to push to origin master, and I was getting different errors now I'm getting this

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

How can I connect my github again? I've tryed multiple different stuff.

Comment: did you get your certificates correctly set up on github and then on the client machine where you are pushing from?

Comment: May you edit the question with the output of `ssh -Tv github.com`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GitHub Error Message - Permission denied (publickey)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940626/github-error-message-permission-denied-publickey)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+Permission+denied+publickey

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a SSH key on your machine generated if not already generated.

This can be done by running following command in your .ssh folder

```
ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -b 521 -f 'filepath/id_ecdsa'
```

More reading on [ssh command](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/keygen/).

This will generate a public and private key pair. You need the public key added to your github account added or for a specific repo.

`cat` `id_ecdsa.pub` and get it added to your github repo's SSH keys.

Note that the name of file above can be anything.  I just named it after the encryption type `ecdsa` preferable.