# git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: git

I'm new to git and anytime i try to push to my repository using "git push origin master", i get this error

git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

i believe i must have incorrectly entered my git credentials (username or password) and the system have saved the incorrect credentials. 
Please how do I delete the already stored credentials so that i can be prompted to enter again my credentials when i want to push to my repository. i use Linus OS.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the origin of the repository? What does the `git remote -v` return?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GitHub Error Message - Permission denied (publickey)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940626/github-error-message-permission-denied-publickey)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Permission+denied+publickey

Answer (score 1):

When using git over ssh, you **need** a public/private key pair.

- If you already have setup a public/private key pair, it would probably be located in `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`.
- If you don't have that setup with GitHub, [you should set that up](https://help.github.com/en/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh)

Alternativly, you can just push to the GitHub repository with HTTPS and your GitHub login, by doing

```
git remote set-url --push https://github.com/<username>/<repository>.git
```

and pushing the repository.

Answer (score 0):

(first create a repository in git, if not created already)

This worked for me:

Step 1- git remote rm origin

Step 2-[select the http option in github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqWnr.png)

step 3- run the following command again

git remote add origin https://github.com/yourdirectory/link.git

git branch -M main

git push -u origin main