# why cannot i push my laravel project to github

Tags: git, github

i have made discussion forum but i cannot push my project to github i have tried all method but it is still not working

i have set ssh key in github.

```
root@miky-Lenovo-ideapad:/opt/lampp/htdocs/discussionforum# git remote add origin git@github.com:milan2056/discussionforum.git
root@miky-Lenovo-ideapad:/opt/lampp/htdocs/discussionforum# git push -u origin master
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

i need to upload my project to github

Comment: Could you try running this command: `ssh -v git@github.com` and [edit] your question and add the output.

Comment: do you want to be asked for username/password when pushing? (help with reverting it to https), or do you want help in setting up the ssh key on github?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GitHub Error Message - Permission denied (publickey)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940626/github-error-message-permission-denied-publickey)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+Permission+denied+publickey

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Github does have some triaging steps for this error that can be found [here](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/error-permission-denied-publickey). Given the error and the url, something likely was not configured correctly when making your SSH key. I would make sure that in your settings it says that you've actually used that ssh key in the past.

Answer (score 0):

i was generating private key as normal user and pushing the project as a root user so i got this error