# Git throwing errors attempting to commit to github

Tags: git, github

I am trying to clone a locally existing repo to github. They suggest doing this:

```
$ git remote add origin git@github.com:Retr0MrWave/MathTiles.git
$ git push -u origin master
```

but when I try to do this an error pops up (after the second command):

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I'm assuming the repo is private as when I try to access https://github.com/Retr0MrWave/MathTiles I get a 404.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GitHub Error Message - Permission denied (publickey)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940626/github-error-message-permission-denied-publickey)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Permission+denied+publickey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like your credentials for GitHub aren't configured correctly. Have you followed this guide [Creating a personal access token for the command line](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line)?

Answer (score 0):

try verify remote repository

```
$ git remote -v
```

before push existing repo.