# Go get not working though windows cmd/powershell but only git bash

Tags: git, go, github, cmd, go-get

I have set up git and got it in my windows system. I have *ssh key* with passphrase. When I get in **git bash** it asks my passphrase and fetches properly but when I do it in **cmd** or **powershell** it throws an error.

```
Cloning into 'go\src\github.com\aws\aws-sdk-go'...
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

(Does not even ask passphrase)
This repo is just example. It happens for all repo.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GitHub Error Message - Permission denied (publickey)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940626/github-error-message-permission-denied-publickey)

Answer (score 0):

ssh was configured but we need to start ssh agent first before typing any go command in terminal/powershell

```
start-ssh-agent
```