# Permission denied (publickey) (Tried every other solution)

Tags: github, ssh

After following all the instructions of Github in [here](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account) and [here](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent) step-by-step to add SSH key to my account and access it via SSH connection I am still hitting the following error:

```
ssh -T (my-user-name)@github.com
Permission denied (publickey)
```

I have also tried the [step-by-step debugging of github](https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.17/user/github/authenticating-to-github/error-permission-denied-publickey) and also this [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940626/github-error-message-permission-denied-publickey) thread. Yet all dead-end for me. I am operating on a Mac OS Catalina 10.15.5. Do I miss any step in between?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `ssh -T (my-user-name)@github.com` will *always* return permission denied.

You don't request a remote secure shell as "my-user-name", ever.

The instructions will always recommend to test your SSH connection with:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
       ^^^
```

Your public key, [registered to your GitHub account](https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.15/user/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account), would then be enough for GitHub to identify you, in that `git` SSH session.