# even after adding public key to GCP ssh keys, get error SSHing in "Permission denied (publickey)"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, virtual-machine

I have a google VM I've been sshing into every day for about six months.

Today all the sudden neither myself or my teammates can get into this machine, either SSH-ing from our own terminals or even trying to use the web terminal gcloud gives you so that I could manually edit the ~/.ssh information on the remote server.

The error each time is just `Permission denied (publickey)`

So far I have:

- regenerated my local value for id_rsa.pub
- uninstalled the google SDK, thinking on reinstallation it would have to cycle in new key values (I know it does some metadata exchange itself...)
- deleting all the project SSH keys, then re-adding the newly generated one
- reinstalled google sdk
- used the [gcloud sdk command line](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/config-ssh) to force regenerate
- oh yeah: obviously cycled the VM on and off to rule out random/silly reasons

I'm pretty lost at the moment. Any advice or people who have gone through similar it is appreciated. I've looked through these questions but either the advice didn't fix it, or it wasn't relevant to my situation:

- [GitHub Error Message - Permission denied (publickey)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940626/github-error-message-permission-denied-publickey)
- [How to solve Permission denied (publickey) error when using Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643502/how-to-solve-permission-denied-publickey-error-when-using-git)
- https://serverfault.com/questions/641453/unable-to-ssh-to-gce-permission-denied-publickey

Comment: Maybe you ran out of disk space... Check serial console logs - if possible paste them in your original post if you're not sure what to look for.

Comment: Are you still can't log in to your VM ?