# Google Source Repository error when doing git push from GCP VM

Tags: git, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-source-repositories

I'm trying to upload a dummy repository to Google Source Repository. I'm doing this to learn how to use this. The steps I did were:

1. Open a GCP VM, created a directory named `test_git` and run `git init`
2. Created a couple of files and folders. Edited the files.
3. Did a `git add <file>`
4. Did a `git commit`
5. Went to Google Source Repository, created an empty repository (same name as the directory) and then, on the VM, did

   `git remote add google ssh://<my@email.com>@source.developers.google.com/p/<PROJECTID>/r/test_git`

This command was found in the Source Repository under the "`Push code from local git repository`"

6. Did `git push --all google`

When I do this, I get an error that says `Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository`.

I honestly don't get it, because around 40 minutes ago I did a `git push` for some actual code (just one python file) and it actually worked (maybe because angels allowed it). And now that I followed some guides, read about how to use git and all stuffs, I'm stuck with this and I don't understand why. I also set a SSH key (generated with `PuTTY`) and registered it, but it didn't worked. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to replicate your problem when I didn't have an SSH key configured on CSR. [Here's a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940626/github-error-message-permission-denied-publickey) related to your concern and I suggest you double check your managed SSH keys.

If the SSH key from PuTTY didn't worked, then you can try generating a new SSH key using terminal (use Git Bash if you're using Windows):

1. Open Terminal.
2. Paste text below:

```
  ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@example.com"
```

3. Enter a file in which to save the key (leave empty & press enter for *default*).
4. Type a secure passphrase (*recommended*) then press enter.
5. If *default* is selected on Step 3, open the file called `id_rsa.pub` and paste the entire text to **Key** when registering the SSH key on Cloud Source Repository. For **Key Name**, it should be something that is easy for you to remember as future reference.

Or as an alternative, you can follow this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/adding-repositories-as-remotes#add_the_repository_as_a_remote) to connect via **HTTPS** instead of **SSH** and run a credential helper script so you don't need to configure SSH keys:

**Windows:**

```
git config --global credential.https://source.developers.google.com.helper gcloud.cmd
```

**Linux or MacOS:**

```
git config --global credential.'https://source.developers.google.com'.helper gcloud.sh
```

Here's a [reference](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials.html) if you want to dig deeper on credential helpers.

Another thing that could help you troubleshoot your problem is to review your Git configuration by running this command:

```
git config --list
```

Comment: The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/adding-repositories-as-remotes#linux-or-macos) part actually worked. But why? I did run the command you posted, but I don't know if it did anything. I run `git remote add google \
https://source.developers.google.com/p/[PROJECT_ID]/r/[REPO_NAME]` and then both `git push --all google` and `git push -u google master` worked. Why?

Comment: When you followed [the document](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/adding-repositories-as-remotes#linux-or-macos), you added the repository as a remote then you were able to push to a Google Cloud repository.

Comment: Notice on your `remote add` command that you are connecting using `https` instead of `ssh`. The credentials that's needed on this part is provided by the helper script.