# GitHub - ERROR: Permission to denied. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists

Tags: git, github, ssh

I am able to do Git clone of repo without any error. But, when I try to push any branch upstream on GitHub, I get the following error:

```
(base) guoling@Guo-MacBook-Pro test % git push --set-upstream origin test-branch

ERROR: Permission to guoling9419/test.git denied to myGitHubUsername.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

**How can I resolve the above issue?**

Here `myGitHubUsername` is my GitHub username.

I have set up ssh public private key pair on my laptop. And, have already added my ssh public key (`id_rsa.pub`) to GitHub page.

I am using `macOS Monterey version 12.4.`

I accidentally overwrote my `~/.ssh/config` file. I have tried to remedy it by doing the following to `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host agent1
        User root
        HostName 198.199.92.88

Host github.com
        HostName github.com
        User git
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host *
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I am following [this dedicated GitHub page](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/error-permission-denied-publickey) and [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940626/github-error-message-permission-denied-publickey) to debug.

When I do `ssh -T git@github.com`, I get the output `Hi myGitHubUsername! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.`

When I do `ssh github`, I get the output `ssh: Could not resolve hostname github: nodename nor servname provided, or not known`

When I do `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"`, I get the output `Agent pid 50031`.

When I do `ssh-add -l -E sha256`, I get the output `The agent has no identities.`

When I do `ssh-add -l -E md5`, I get the output `The agent has no identities.`

Comment: What URL did you configure git to use as the origin repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is that user `myGitHubUsername` does not have permission to access repository `guoling9419/test.git`.  Nothing you do with ssh will change *that* fact, though things you do with ssh can change who GitHub *believe you to be*.

> When I do `ssh -T git@github.com`, I get the output `Hi myGitHubUsername! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.`

Assuming `myGitHubUsername` is the correct name, you're already all set on your mac.  You just need to give `myGitHubUsername` permission to access repository `guoling9419/test.git` on GitHub (presumably through the GitHub web interface, or perhaps through their `gh` cli), or change the URL to point to whatever repository you're supposed to be using instead of `guoling9419/test.git`, using `git remote set-url origin new-url` for instance.

#### The remainder of this is optional reading

> I am using `macOS Monterey version 12.4`.
>
> When I do `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"` ...

Don't do that on macOS: modern macOS sets up a user agent for you at the time you log in on your laptop (or whatever hardware) so that there's one already provided.

(It's not technically *harmful* to start a new one like this, but that disables some useful features.)

> When I do `ssh-add -l` ...

Note that `-l` merely *lists the currently-added identities*.  If you need to add some identities, use `ssh-add` *without* `-l`.  See the documentation for details.