# problem to push files on a repository git

Tags: git, ssh, git-push

I'm having trouble with Git. I'm trying to push the master but I apparently have a problem with the new ssh key.

```bash
willy@DESKTOP-MH62RJV MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Desktop/booki (master)
$ git push --force ssh master
```

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Do you've an idea ??

I also tried to clone it but the same:

```bash
willy@DESKTOP-MH62RJV MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Desktop/booki (master)
$ git clone git@github.com:RodolpheACHY/booki.git
```

```
Cloning into 'booki'...
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

willy@DESKTOP-MH62RJV MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Desktop/booki (master)

Comment: One doesn't push files -- one pushes commits (which refer to trees, which refer to files). That's irrelevant here, though -- your problem is with SSH authentication, not with anything happening at a higher level.

Comment: Anyhow, the first thing you (and we) need to know is how you _intended_ this to work. Do you have a key sitting in `~/.ssh` on disk? Or is your key in a smartcard or yubikey and accessed through an agent? Is that agent running? Does `ssh-add -l` show the key in question? Go back and remember how you set this up in the first place -- you and we need to know that to know why it's not working now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12940626/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/2643502/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Permission+denied+publickey